# route53, elasticbeanstalk and custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have an express, node, mongo app running on `elasticbeanstalk` perfectly. the url value of this `elasticbeanstalk` is something like `example.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

Now I also have customer domain, lets say `example.com` which is registered on `aws route53` and in the hostedzone I have `soa` and `ns` record.

I wanted to load `elasticbeanstalk` when user visit my custom domain `example.com`. I have tried following aws docs 
`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html` with no luck.

I have created `A` record with alias that targets `elasticbeanstalk` environment url value. I have tried creating `cname` record as well. Waited over 48 hours but still my `example.com` doesn't load any app.

I am not an expert on any of these issue. **Please** help me.

**Please note, my `example.com` domain was pointing to a `cloudfont` and `s3` bucket before.**

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've route53 NS entries in your domain provider console so **example.com** can resolve to your ElasticBeanstalk LoadBalancer address. After you have entered nameserver entries in domain provider console check if DNS servers are propagated successfully. MoreOver for domain entry select **A** record type with Alias to your ElasticBeanstalks's LocadBalancer address.

Comment: hi @matesio thanks for the reply mate. I have purchase `example.com` from aws. And when i created ElasticBeanstalk app, I didn't get any LoadBalancer. In fact if I go `configuration` under my ElasticBeanstalk app, it says `This configuration does not contain a load balancer.`

Comment: Then it should be elasticbeanstalk endpoint. Check name servers for your site using this https://dnschecker.org/ns-lookup.php, if it shows aws nameservers or not ?

Comment: hello mate, thanks again for the reply.  I have checked using dbschecker.org. It shows right NS records. 

I have created two alias `A` records - One for `example.com` and another one for `www.example.com` 
Both points to `elasticbeanstalk` environment endpoint. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. :(

Comment: I am bit confused here. from https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php I can see the record for my app. From route53, If I select a record, and click test, the result comes with no error. If i take the ip address and paste in the url, I can see the site. But when I visit the directly to chefcooks.io, I see site can't be reached!! Please help.

Comment: hey @jahid DNS's are progated correctly https://dnspropagation.net/A/chefcooks.io and now chefcooks.io is showing elasticbeanstalk page.